# winjs appbar.wincontrol is null

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, appbar

I am creating a Windows 8 HTML5 app, and implementing an app bar. When I access the appbar.winControl it is always null. So if for example I write appbar.winControl.show() I get an exception claiming that winControl is null.

What I did was create a fixed layout app. Without doing anything else, I added the following markup in the document body:

```
<body>
<div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" aria-label="Command Bar">
    <button id="btnBoardSizeUp" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{label:'Larger', icon:'zoomout', section:'global', tooltip:'Increase the board size'}" />
    <button id="btnBoardSizeDown" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{label:'Smaller', icon:'zoomin', section:'global', tooltip:'Decrease the board size'}" />
    <button id="btnAbortGame" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{label:'Abort', icon:'cancel', section:'selection', tooltip:'Abort the current game'}" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var appbar = document.getElementById("appbar");
    var winControl = appbar.winControl;
    winControl.show();
</script>
```

The line winControl.show() produces the following error:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference

As far as I can see I have implemented the appbar correctly on the page, so it should work. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page Controls are not initialized yet and script is executing before that.

There is two place this code can be placed. either in

```
// if the app bar is part of default.html, appbar show can be put in default.js
// default.js already have a call to WinJS.UI.processAll under activated event handler
WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function ()
{
    appbar.winControl.show();
});
```

or

```
// if the appbar is part of mypage.html, need to have code like this in mypage.js
WinJS.UI.Pages.define('/pages/mypage/mypage.html',
    {
         ready: function onready(element, options)
         {
             appbar.winControl.show();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sushil. I could not get the first example to work - instead getting an error saying that the processAll function did not exist. But the second example worked perfectly, so my problem is solved.

Comment: I have to amend that. Now I can get both exmples to work. I don't know why the first example didn't work earlier, but it could have been a typing error on my part that I just couldn't spot. Anyway, thanks again, @Sushil

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a winjs control (div with data-win-control attribute) to specify the control you want.
You must also call the WinJS.UI.processAll function in your JavaScript code. WinJS.UI.processAll parses your markup and instantiates any Windows Library for JavaScript controls it finds.

1. If you aren't using the Blank Application template or if you're
   adding the control to a page that you created yourself, you might
   need to add a call to WinJS.UI.processAll.
2. If you added the control
   to your app's home page (which is usually the default.html file),
   add    a call to WinJS.UI.processAll in your onactivated event
   handler, as    shown in the previous example
3. If you added the  control to a Page    control, you don't need to add a call to
   WinJS.UI.processAll because    the Page control does that for you
   automatically.
4. If you added the    control to another page that is
   not your app's home page, handle the    DOMContentLoaded event and
   use the handler to call    WinJS.UI.processAll.

function initialize() {

```
WinJS.UI.processAll();
```

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialize(), false);