# winControl property is giving null object in Windows 8 app development

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime

On loading an another HTML page, which is having semanticzoom as one of the divs in which ZoomIn and ZoomOut are two bounded list views (WinJS.UI.ListView)

When i try to access the following code -

```
   WinJS.UI.Fragments.render("/OpenStore.html", target).done(
        function completed(r) {
              var zoomedOutList = document.getElementById("ZoomOut").winControl;
   }
   );
```

So it gives zoomedOutList as a null object even though there exist an element by id "ZoomOut"

I have also tried the following link but it too doesn't work for me  - 
[winjs appbar.wincontrol is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986779/winjs-appbar-wincontrol-is-null)

```
    WinJS.UI.processAll();
```

I needed to add this before

```
    var zoomedOutList = document.getElementById("ZoomOut").winControl;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's been created/activated properly? `data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SemanticZoom"` for example? Please add the HTML code for the control if that's already there.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but i think I found the answer. I'll add it.

Comment: Call `processAll` on just the target element, to avoid unnecessary DOM scanning looking for controls to activate.